# How can I access a key value in jsonb postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

```
{
    "data": {
        "val": "{\"cell_number\": \"123\"}"
    }
}
```

I want to get the value in data -> val -> cell_number i.e '123'. Is there a way to do it in postgresql?

Comment: Is it really like that?  You have an escaped JSON object at the `val` key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is not a typo and you put a stringified json object under the `val` key, then this will untangle it for you:

```
with invar as (
  select '{
    "data": {
        "val": "{\"cell_number\": \"123\"}"
    }
}'::jsonb as jsonb_col
)
select ((jsonb_col->'data'->>'val')::jsonb)->>'cell_number' from invar;

 ?column? 
----------
 123
(1 row)
```

The first step gets you down to the `val` key.  That result has to be returned as `text` (hence the `->>`) and then cast to `jsonb` so that `cell_number` can be dereferenced.